# Updating to Ubuntu 15.04, my Flex compiler stopped working

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flex4

After updating Ubuntu to 15.04, I cannot compile my Flex applications using IntelliJ 13. These are the logs:

[image]

When I run the command by command line, I get the following error:

[image]

What can I do to fix it? No apparent code error appears, it looks like compiler/library configuration.

**Edit**:

- Tried to install a newer version of Flex and AIR. Still happens.
- I have no strange firewall option in my iptables (have nothing at all when querying `iptables -L`).
- I am reinstalling (`sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`) the exact same version (perhaps with some updates).

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that your Java installation was corrupted with the Upgrade? Have you tried reinstalling JDK?
I see you are using Oracle JDK as IntelliJ expects.
This should not be a problem with Ubuntu, I would recommend reinstalling JDK and InteliJ/Flex Compiler. Maybe they have newer versions that deal with that problem.

However the Error not shown in the IDE is an [ConnectException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html) from java.
"Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port)."
You can see it has something to do with your Sockets from the Terminal Log.
Even the Flex Compiler fails to open a Socket.

Perhaps those sockets became inaccessible after the Upgrade for some reason.
Check your Firewall if that Ubuntu version has one on. And check if you 
have access to the sockets you are trying to use.